# netbeans no me muestra el valor de una variable en modo debug

Tags: java, netbeans

Quería monitorizar el valor de una variable (i). Para ello doy clic derecho en la variable y añado un `watch`. Pero ejecuto el programa en modo debug y en el valor de la variable me sale:

> "no current context"

¿cómo puedo visualizar el valor de una variable mientras el programa está en ejecución?

```
public class PruebaDebug {

   
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
      int i=0;
      while(i<10000000)
      {
          i++;
          Thread.sleep(1000);
      }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje que obtienes es seguramente:

> No current context (stack frame)

**Este mensaje indica que el depurador no puede evaluar la variable, porque la variable no se encuentra en la memoria en su punto de interrupción**, por lo tanto, lo que debes realizar es agregar un punto de interrupción (Breakpoint) para poder monitorear el valor de la variable sin problema.

[image: Jorgesys Netbeans brreakpoint]